# Reading files with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I have a folder containing approximately 18,000 files and I'd like to open them using the `Windows.Storage` namespace. Since the namespace is shared between Store applications and Windows Phone 8 apps I thought the same code would work the same on each device ; though I have very little experience in developping for Windows Phone 8.

```
    StorageFolder current = await CreateFolder(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "name");

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files;

    files = await current.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, startIndex, maxItemsToRetrieve);
```

Without the parameters I successfully get the 18,000 `StorageFile`. However, I don't want to get them all at the same time (it'd be kind of heavy) so I tried sending for instance `0` as the `startIndex` and `50` as the `maxItemsToRetrieve` parameters. On both Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 I get the fifty first files in the folder.

Now the issue is when I try to get the following files in the folder (by sending for instance `51` and `50` ; I should get the files from 51 to 101). It works on Windows 8 but on Windows Phone 8 I get an empty list of `StorageFile`.  It seems a rather unique case because I could not find anybody with this issue on the internet so I'm probably doing something wrong / missing something. Could you help me please?

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is a wp8 bug

Comment: For Windows Phone 8: Are the files located inside your project in the solution in a folder or you save then in the isolated storage of the application?

Comment: they are in the isolated storage of the application

Answer (score 0):

`CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery` is not supported in Windows Phone. I'm pretty sure all the `CommonFileQuery` will throw an exception if you try to use. Just get files without this and use `LINQ` or something to order the list your self.

PS : `defaultquery` is the default and you don't need to explicitly say it.

Comment: `//Fill the list with all the latest reports.
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFolder reportsFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync( "AutoTestReports", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists );
    var listOfFiles = await reportsFolder.GetFilesAsync();
    var listOfFilesOrdered = listOfFiles.OrderByDescending( a => a.DateCreated );`

Comment: yes okay but that does not answer the question ; with the call `GetFilesAsync` you will get the 18,000 files while I want to (sort of) paginate them.

Comment: @RedPolygon to be honest with you.  And your not going to like this, this is most likely more Microsoft CRAP.  This is probably a bug and there is most likely nothing you can do about it.  Wish I had better advice, but developing on the Windows Phone I have found many things that dont work, are broken or just flat out were never implemented.

Comment: @RedPolygon did you try other tests, like maybe offset of 1 and a limit of 2 or any other tests.  Is only offset of 0 working with any limit or...   ??